# View is missing from the Dropdown

Tags: android

I'm working with the Android Studio Version 3.5.1. When I tried to clone a project from git which was built in lower Android Studio version the project built without making an error. But I can not find the "Android" view from the Views dropdown menu. As shown in the below image.

My Project Structure View

[image]

Looking forward to a favorable response!
Thank you!!

Comment: This usually happens when the project is not built properly. Still, if you are able to run the app the try fil>Invalidate and restart option

Comment: @SatyajitDas I tried that as well but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you didn't import the project correctly. 
Here are the steps to import your project correctly.

In Github click the "Clone or download" button of the project you want to import --> download the ZIP file and unzip it.

In Android Studio Go to File -> New Project -> Import Project and select the newly unzipped folder -> press OK. It will build the Gradle automatically.

Make sure you are connecting with the internet. Sometimes android need to download some dependencies.

I hope it will resolve your problem.

Good Luck with your project.

Comment: If it didn't work,
Go to File --> Invalidate Cashes/restart.
I hope it will sole the issue.

Comment: tried in both ways sir but still didn't fix the issue :-|

Comment: I have cloned the project directly from git. Actually, what's the difference between cloning and importing a downloaded project?
Thank you for your support!